# Using selenium wait until in katalon studio, Groovy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio, webdriverwait

So I have been trying to implement wait function from selenium to a katalon groovy script, and I keep getting an error for line the following line

```
   WebUI.wait.Until(FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Fund Metrics Trend']")), 10)
```

here is my code if anyone could tell me why I am getting the following error:

Reason:[0;39m
[31mgroovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: wait for class: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords[0;39m
[31m    at Tabs Permissions.run(Tabs Permissions:54)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:321)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:291)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:283)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:222)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:106)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:97)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)[0;39m
[31m    at TempTestCase1545063637352.run(TempTestCase1545063637352.groovy:22)[0;39m
2018-12-17 11:21:19.430 [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36mc.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   -[0;39m [31m❌ Test Cases/Tabs Permissions FAILED.[0;39m
[31mReason:[0;39m
[31mgroovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: wait for class: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords[0;39m
[31m    at Tabs Permissions.run(Tabs Permissions:54)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:321)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:291)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:283)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:222)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:106)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:97)[0;39m
[31m    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)[0;39m
[31m    at TempTestCase1545063637352.run(TempTestCase1545063637352.groovy:22)[0;39m
2018-12-17 11:21:19.430 [34mINFO [0;39m [36mc.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   -[0;39m [39mEND Test Cases/Tabs Permissions

```
   import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
   import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
   import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
   import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
   import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
   import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
   import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
   import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
   import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
   import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
   import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
   import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
   import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
   import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
   import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

   //set Web UI delay between actions to 2 seconds Project, Settings, Execution, Default, Web UI

   TestData data = findTestData('Investor/Notes')
   //TestData data = findTestData('temp')

   WebUI.openBrowser('')
   WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()



   WebUI.navigateToUrl(GlobalVariable.url)
   WebUI.maximizeWindow()


   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, long time=10)

   for (def index : (0..data.getRowNumbers() - 1)) {

    WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Login/Screen Elements/input_username'),               data.internallyGetValue('username', index))
       WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Login/Screen Elements/input_password'), data.internallyGetValue('password', index))
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Login/Screen Elements/button_Login'))
if ((data.internallyGetValue('username', index) == 'jasmine') || (data.internallyGetValue('username', index) == 'pefadmin4') || (data.internallyGetValue('username', index) == 'pefreviewer4') || (data.internallyGetValue('username', index) == 'pefreadonly4') || (data.internallyGetValue('username', index) == 'fundaccounting4'))  {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Client/a_DFW Capital Partners'))
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Fund/a_DFW Capital Partners V L.P.'))
    WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Tabs Permissions/a_Dashboard'), 10)
    WebUI.delay(3)
    WebUI.wait.Until(FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Fund Metrics Trend']")), 10)
    WebUI.delay(3)
    WebUI.verifyTextPresent("Fund Metrics Trend", false)
```

P.S. this is only the upper part of my code, everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Katalon Studio you could replace this line

```
WebUI.wait.Until(FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Fund Metrics Trend']")), 10)
```

with the following (test object will be created and then a wait will be implemented):

```
TestObject fundMetricsTrend = new TestObject().addProperties("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "//*[contains(text(), 'Fund Metrics Trend']") //this is the test object definition
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(fundMetricsTrend, 10)
```

NOTE:

You will need to import these

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
```

Also, you can try any of the various `WebUI.waitFor_______()` functions to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error message because the 'wait' is not available in WebUI class.
An example of using wait in Katalon Studio is:

```html
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('findTestObject('Login/Screen Elements/input_username''), 
        0)
```